# Libreoffice Calc: Custom x axis label

Tags: label, diagram, libreoffice, calc

I am trying to create a diagram in Libreoffice calc, where the x axis labels shall be intervals and the y axis labels shall be shown in percentage.

My table looks like this:

```
0-40        100%
40-70       96%
70-100      92%
100-130     84%
>130        63%
```

Unfortunately, the y axis labels are shown correct, but the x axis labels look like this, instead of labeling it with the given intervals:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Where the diagram begins with x=1 and ends up with x = 6.

I did not find a way to make calc label the x axis as specified and also did not find any help online. Probably someone knows?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Edit the **Data Series** for your chart and let *Categories* point to the fields in your table that hold the labels.

1. When in edit mode for your chart (simply double-click it, if not), right click and select *Data Ranges...*.
2. Select the *Data Series* tab.
3. For each of the **Data series** make sure they point to the same fields containing your labels.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what worked for me:

When you go insert an `object -> graph`,

choose `XY Scatter`, and NOT Line Graph.

`XY Scatter` will automatically put your first column selected as your x axis.

With `XY Scatter`, there is a data range entry option called `"x axis"`.

A line graph will not and it appears impossible to ever create a data range called `"x axis"`.